# JOLT spec for ternary operation

Tags: jolt

I am trying to write a jolt spec for conversion of the following input in the expected output mentioned below

INPUT :

`{
  "city": "Seattle",
  "state": "WA",
  "country": "US",
  "date": "10/20/2018",
  "userList": [
    {
      "name": "David",
      "age": "22",
      "sex": "M",
      "company": "good"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tom",
      "age": "30",
      "sex": "M",
      "company": "good"
    },
    {
      "name": "Annie",
      "age": "25",
      "sex": "F",
      "company": "bad"
    },
    {
      "name": "Aaron",
      "age": "27",
      "sex": "M",
      "company": "bad"
    }
  ]
}`

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

`{
  "users" : [ {
    "date" : "10/20/2018",
    "username" : "David",
    "age" : "22",
    "sex" : "M",
    "organization" : "good"
  }, {
    "date" : "10/20/2018",
    "username" : "Tom",
    "age" : "30",
    "sex" : "M",
    "organization" : "good"
  } ],
  "Date" : "10/20/2018",
  "State" : "WA",
  "Country" : "US"
}`

I want to filter out all the elements in the list where company = bad or sex = F.Or alternatively keep only the elements where company = good and sex=M.
I need help in removing the elements from the list based on the specific conditions.
Is jolt recommended for such data driven conversions?

The Spec that I have written so far is
`[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userList": {
        "*": {
          "name": "users.[&1].username",
          "age": "users.[&1].age",
          "sex": "users.[&1].sex",
          "company": "users.[&1].organization",
          "@(2,date)": "users.[&1].date"
        }
      },
      "date": "Date",
      "state": "State",
      "country": "Country"
    }
    }
]`

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is the process I followed to come up to a solution for the "take all M+good"

1. copy top level element as-is, not impacting the scope
2. for users content, go to the first field used for filtering "users -> * -> sex -> M" and copy all fields in that case
3. do the same for the other field used for filtering
4. in step 2 and 3, I used a map to avoid the "null" in the array. Now switching back to array

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userList": {
        "*": {
          "name": "users.[&1].username",
          "age": "users.[&1].age",
          "sex": "users.[&1].sex",
          "company": "users.[&1].organization",
          "@(2,date)": "users.[&1].date"
        }
      },
      "date": "Date",
      "state": "State",
      "country": "Country"
    }
    }
  ,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "users": {
        "*": {
          "sex": {
            "M": {
              "@(2,username)": "users.&3.username",
              "@(2,age)": "users.&3.age",
              "@(2,sex)": "users.&3.sex",
              "@(2,organization)": "users.&3.organization",
              "@(2,date)": "users.&3.date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  ,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "users": {
        "*": {
          "organization": {
            "good": {
              "@(2,username)": "users.&3.username",
              "@(2,age)": "users.&3.age",
              "@(2,sex)": "users.&3.sex",
              "@(2,organization)": "users.&3.organization",
              "@(2,date)": "users.&3.date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
     },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "users": {
        "*": "users[]"
      }
    }
 }
]
```

For the other case, you just have to change the filter rules to do nothing when the rule match and copy the field in the other cases (*). Which give following spec (did it only on first field, updating for second field should not be an issue)

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userList": {
        "*": {
          "name": "users.[&1].username",
          "age": "users.[&1].age",
          "sex": "users.[&1].sex",
          "company": "users.[&1].organization",
          "@(2,date)": "users.[&1].date"
        }
      },
      "date": "Date",
      "state": "State",
      "country": "Country"
    }
    }
  ,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "users": {
        "*": {
          "sex": {
            "F": null,
            "*": {
              "@(2,username)": "users.&3.username",
              "@(2,age)": "users.&3.age",
              "@(2,sex)": "users.&3.sex",
              "@(2,organization)": "users.&3.organization",
              "@(2,date)": "users.&3.date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   },

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "users": {
        "*": "users[]"
      }
    }
 }
]
```